# how to extrac multiple rows from one colum

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to ask a simple question I think is simple my question is the next I am making in my website a page that will report the images and description from a database and I'm using PDO to the consulting so the code is the next as follows

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT ruta_img_tutorial,descripcion_paso_imagen,titulo_tutorial FROM tutoriales");
//$stmt->bindParam("titulo",$tituloformula,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
// para sacar el objeto que vamos a referenciar abajo
$data=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);// para sacar el objeto que vamos a referenciar abajo
$count=$stmt->rowCount();// cuenta las filas y las mete en un array

$db = null;
// hacer un bucle for para guardar todala la informacion 
$imagen = json_decode($data->ruta_img_tutorial);
$desc_img= json_decode($data->descripcion_paso_imagen);
```

so in the data a refer all to an obj to then after take each one I always do a for each to take the array from the decode of Jason I've never had a problem but the thing is when I report the rows there are 3 in the list but in the for each only shows 1 of them how this is possible and how I can go through the 3 rows and show every single column ty so much for all

ok here is the change made with the fechall

```
try{
        $db = getDB();
        $arraydescrip=[];
        $arrayimagen=[];

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT ruta_img_tutorial,descripcion_paso_imagen,titulo_tutorial FROM tutoriales");
        //$stmt->bindParam("titulo",$tituloformula,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        // para sacar el objeto que vamos a referenciar abajo
        $data=$stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);// para sacar el objeto que vamos a referenciar abajo
        $count=$stmt->rowCount();// cuenta las filas y las mete en un array
        $db = null;
        // hacer un bucle for para guardar todala la informacion 
        $imagen = json_decode($data->ruta_img_tutorial);
        $desc_img= json_decode($data->descripcion_paso_imagen);
        foreach ($imagen as $value){
            echo '<a><img style="width: 400px; height: 400px;" class="img-thumbnail" src="'.$value.'"></a>';
        }
        foreach ($desc_img as $value){
            array_push($arraydescrip, $value);
        }

        foreach ($imagen as $value){
            array_push($arrayimagen, $value);
        }
        print var_dump($arrayimagen);
        // para que no de error de index of tenemos que poner en el for < solo sin el igual ya que para contar el array siempre tiene que ser menor que el total de array 
        for($j=0;$j<count($arrayimagen);$j++){
            echo '<a data-fancybox href="'.$arrayimagen[$j].'"><img style="width: 400px; height: 400px;" class="img-thumbnail" src="'.$arrayimagen[$j].'"></a>';
            echo'<figcaption style="width: 400px; text-align: justify;" >'.wordwrap($arraydescrip[$j],1000,"<br><br>").'</figcaption>';
        }


}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
}
```

no, it gives me notices several notices that I am not referring to an obj that why I want the solution for it or why it gives that notice reporting

> Notice: Trying to get property 'ruta_img_tutorial' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\PaginaWebPirotecniaGrupo\classes\tutosupload.php on line 110
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'descripcion_paso_imagen' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\PaginaWebPirotecniaGrupo\classes\tutosupload.php on line 112
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\PaginaWebPirotecniaGrupo\classes\tutosupload.php on line 113
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\PaginaWebPirotecniaGrupo\classes\tutosupload.php on line 116
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\PaginaWebPirotecniaGrupo\classes\tutosupload.php on line 120
>   array(0) { }

ok i make this new lines at now it get all from the data base

```
 $db = getDB();
        $arraydescrip=[];
        $arrayimagen=[];

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT ruta_img_tutorial,descripcion_paso_imagen,titulo_tutorial FROM tutoriales");
        //$stmt->bindParam("titulo",$tituloformula,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        // para sacar el objeto que vamos a referenciar abajo
        $data=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);// para sacar el objeto que vamos a referenciar abajo
        $count=$stmt->rowCount($data);// cuenta las filas y las mete en un array
        $db = null;
        // hacer un bucle for para guardar todala la informacion 

        //$desc_img= json_decode($data->descripcion_paso_imagen);
        foreach ($data as $row){
            $imagen = json_decode($row->ruta_img_tutorial);
            foreach($imagen as $value){
            echo '<a><img style="width: 400px; height: 400px;" class="img-thumbnail" src="'.$value.'"></a>';

            }
        }
```

Comment: There is little point preparing a query with no parameters

Comment: These 2 lines WONT do what you think `$imagen = json_decode($data->ruta_img_tutorial);
        $desc_img= json_decode($data->descripcion_paso_imagen);` Do a `print_r($data)` to see the array you are dealing with

Comment: @Rigg it doses when I do it with fetch but not with fetch all

Comment: Please show us an example of at least one row that was returned from the database

Comment: my question or new question here is how can i get only the firts image of each array on the for each to show as a thumbnail

Comment: Then you need to write a new question please

Comment: cant make more questions for the negative vote

Answer (score 4):

Fetch all of the rows instead of one row. Change:

```
$data=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

To:

```
$data=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: gives this notices Notice: Trying to get property 'ruta_img_tutorial' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\PaginaWebPirotecniaGrupo\classes\tutosupload.php on line 110

Notice: Trying to get property 'descripcion_paso_imagen' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\PaginaWebPirotecniaGrupo\classes\tutosupload.php on line 111

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\PaginaWebPirotecniaGrupo\classes\tutosupload.php on line 112

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\PaginaWebPirotecniaGrupo\classes\tutosupload.ph

Comment: Edit your post and show us the whole code then. Here there's nothing related to any foreach loop.

Comment: Also replace `$count=$stmt->rowCount();` with `$count = count($data);`

Comment: @RiggI am not using at all the rowcount only in a for that I don't use any more but thanks so much I think I don't need to add it cause I am counting the smt statement

Comment: @guillermo Thats a handy line of code then, there just to use up a few CPU cycles you were doing nothing with I assume

Comment: @guillermo Loop over your results with `foreach ($data as $row) { ...` Then get current row data with `$row->ruta_img_tutorial`  etc... You don't need json_decode or anything else

Comment: @PHP yes I need it because in the base I got the date of the image coded in json in one line so if I don't do that I cant to recover the routes of the images

Comment: So sorry but that's probably poorly done, there's absolutely no point doing this since dates are primitive sql type. But even in this case you would need something like `json_decode($row->your_date_json_encoded)`

Comment: @PHP sorry wasent date is the rute of the image in my server that i have json code de date i ahve it normal